# Share data between users in metro application

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I would like to create a Metro application that allows a group of people to interact.  One person would create data and serve as the owner, and multiple others would be invited in and be allow to modify that data.  I heard from Build talks that each Metro application will get per-user Azure storage, but will it be possible to share that data between multiple users?  Does anyone have a link they could share where I could research this?

Comment: Are you sure about the Azure storage or do you mean SkyDrive? SkyDrive is bound to a live id and as far as I know you would have to hand out permissions. Azure is another thing and you could create a web service that checks permissions.

Comment: There is a calculator for Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a more formal definition of this with the updated help now available.  They were referring to roaming application data.  I found the following links that provide guidance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx

The general is that a small amount of temporary application data is provided on a per-app, per-user basis.  The actual size you get is not detailed, but the guidance is pretty clear - app settings only, no large data sets, and don't use it for instant synchronization.  Given this guidance, my plan is not a good one and will change.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are confusing SkyDrive with Azure Blob Storage.

**SkyDrive**

- Personal to a Live ID
- Not really meant as a base for collaborative work

**Azure Blob Storage**

- You can have public files that anyone can view and update
- You can have a lease on file that only allows certain people to edit it
- Since you own the Azure account you also control the content
- You can learn the basics [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/smarx/Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage)

Comment: Yes, since posting I have learned that SkyDrive is what they mean, I think.  They said during one of the talks that there would be free per-user, per-app storage.  Now it looks like SkyDrive is what they were referring to, but I still haven't seen a clear statement to that effect.  SkyDrive seems more like consumer-end data, not private app data.

Comment: @PatrickV He answered you question.  SkyDrive is personal to a live ID.  +1 for vonLochow since you did not get the check.

Comment: @Blam He did not answer it adequately, at least not unless I am missing something.  The link provided is on Windows Azure Blob storage.  I was asking about the Metro free per-application storage.  To the best of my knowledge, Azure Blob Storage is a for-pay service.  I haven't had a chance to follow up on this yet unfortunately, been a busy 6 months.

Comment: @PatrickV Read the first sentence.  Confusing SkyDrive with Blog means you get a free SkyDrive not Blob with your Live account.

Comment: @Blam Read my first comment.  Focus on the "I still haven't seen a clear statement" part.  I really want to close this out and award an answer here, unfortunately I need to do due diligence from my end, and have higher priorities at the moment.  SkyDrive may be what they meant, but neither SkyDrive nor Blob storage match "free per-application, per-user storage".  Blob fails "free", while SkyDrive fails "per application".

Comment: @PatrickV OK what you want is not free.  But that was not the question.  I will try an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share private app data between users, the best way to do so would be via a shared server of some sort.  You should have a server (running on Azure, Amazon EC2, or anything really) that exposes a REST-ful web service which each application connects to.  The shared state then lives on that server.

This is better than trying to use skydrive or some file-based system for storing shared data.  With a file on skydrive and multiple users trying to access it, you would run into concurrency issues when more than 1 person tries to write to it.

Comment: The problem there is that I believe those all cost money.  I'm new to the mobile market, and I'm not sure how the cost of running a cloud service will affect the pricing model.  If there's a free path, I'd prefer that.  Given some domain specific bandwidth concerns, I'm also considering just using a local server on the LAN.  Need some prototype speed tests to inform that decision though - I'd rather not make the users run a server if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get Azure with Metro.

With Live you get a free SkyDrive that is a personal cloud storage.   Like 10 GB.   Can share files but it is via sending an email link.   It is not file storage that would readily support a server type application to manage that sharing.

Azure is a cloud platform for file and data sharing.  Azure is not free but storage cost is only $0.125 / GB per month. 10 GB = $1.25 / month.  Using SkyDrive as shared storage you are giving up a lot of developer and hosting tools that come with Azure to save $1.25 / month.

Comment: See my answer, you do actually get "cloud" storage on a per-user, per-app basis.  This is not the same as a for-pay azure service (and if I made it sound like that it was a misstatement on my part, I never intended to state that).  I certainly never wanted to use SkyDrive to store this data - it should be app-managed, not user-managed.  Your guidance here is dead on.  For a free app, any cost I can avoid is desirable, looks like this one maybe is not.

Comment: No.  Roaming configuration data, which at the time I asked this question was not defined, is what I was referring to by the following sentence: "I heard from Build talks that each Metro application will get per-user Azure storage, but will it be possible to share that data between multiple users?"  There is a very valid question there that went completely unanswered until I answered it myself yesterday.  I do appreciate the feedback, but I can do without the ad-hominem attacks, as can this community as a whole.